# How would I get JSON information into, say, a variable, from a function using a callback in Javascript (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Alright, this could be really obvious, and I may not have worded the title correctly, I don't know.

I have this command that gets information on a starcraft profile, using [this](https://github.com/benweier/battlenet-api) battlenet api. The function used to get a profiles information is

`sc2.profile.profile({ id: profileId, region: profileRegion, name: profileName }, callback)`

I want to be able to use the information from there for something else, and I want to pick and choose what I send and what I don't. Example:

`console.log("Profile Name: " + response.displayName) /*response being the JSON, displayName being the only thing out of the JSON to be sent */`

How would I go about doing that? Unfortunately I have to have a callback, and so far I haven't been able to use

`var profileInfo = sc2.profile.profile({ id: profileId, region: profileRegion, name: profileName }, callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/benweier/battlenet-api

> callback Required. The callback function accepts two arguments error
>   and response.
>
> error is only applicable when there's a connection issue to the API.
>   Otherwise null. body is the request response body parsed as JSON. If a
>   request is successful this value can still return API errors such as
>   'Character not found' or 'Account forbidden'. res is the response
>   information such as headers and statusCode

so your code would look like this

```
let someData;
sc2.profile.profile({ id: profileId, region: profileRegion, name: profileName },
    (err, body, res) => { 
        // this function will be called when you receive response / error
        someData = body.someData
     }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use callback function and assign the result to a variable as following :

```
var profileInfo;
sc2.profile.profile({ id: profileId, region: profileRegion, name: profileName }, function(err,body,res){
profileInfo = res;
})
```